# Java HTTP-Request with POST-Data

Tags: java, android, http-request

I wrote the following code in java to send some data via POST-Variables to a PHP-File of my website and then I want to get the source code of this website.

```
public DatabaseRequest(String url, IDatabaseCallback db_cb)
        {
            this.db_cb = db_cb;
            site_url = url;
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            request = new HttpPost(site_url);
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(0);
        }

        public void addParameter(List<NameValuePair> newNameValuePairs)
        {
            nameValuePairs = newNameValuePairs;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            db_cb.databaseFinish(getContent());
        }

        public String[] getContent()
        {

            String result = "";
            try {
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
                result = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String[] result_arr = result.trim().split("<br>");
            for (int i = 0; i < result_arr.length; i++)
            {
                result_arr[i] = result_arr[i].trim();
            }
            return result_arr;
        }
```

When I want to run this code, then eclipse throws the following error message:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: How do you run this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// executes the request and gets the response.
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPostRequest);
// get the status code--- 200 = Http.OK
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
responseBody = httpEntity.getContent();    

if (statusCode = 200) {
    // process the responseBody. 
}
else{
    // there is some error in responsebody
}
```

**EDIT:** To handle `UnsupportedEncodingException`

Before making HTTP request you need to encode the post data in order to convert all string data into valid url format.

```
// Url Encoding the POST parameters
try {
    httpPostRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // writing error to Log
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: For responseBody you can use String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Comment: this throws a Unsupported Encoding Error (uft-8). Do I have to set a different encoding type for my PHP file?

Comment: could you plz paste the logcat?